# Help me optimize this jQuery :has selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I'm using dynaTrace to profile my application in Internet Explorer.

One of the most expensive calls is the following:

```
$("div.containerClass:has(div.containerHeader)")
```

I scoped the selector as follows, which offered a little improvement:

```
$("div.containerClass:has(div.containerHeader)", "#section-wrapper")
```

How can I improve the performance further?

**NOTE: I CANNOT change the HTML markup, only the JavaScript.**

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.

**UDPATE**
Here is sample HTML... note that in my actual application, the HTML is dynamic and the actual markup will vary:

```
<div id="section-wrapper">
    <div class="somethingelse">
        <div class="somethingelse2">
            <div class="containerClass"> 
            <div class="containerHeader"> 
              <h2>content region 1</h2> 
            </div> 
            </div> 

            <div class="containerClass"> 
            <div> 
              <h2>content region 2</h2> 
            </div> 
            </div> 

            <div class="containerClass"> 
            <div class="containerHeader"> 
              <h2>content region3 </h2> 
            </div> 
            </div> 

            <div class="containerClass"> 
            <div class="containerHeader"> 
              <h2>content region 4</h2> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a single selector, like this:

```
$("#section-wrapper div.containerClass:has(div.containerHeader)")
```

Otherwise you're firing up multiple jQuery objects just to perform a find.  You'll have to test, but depending on the DOM you're working against, this can be *much* faster (especially in jQuery 1.4.3+):

```
$("#section-wrapper div.containerHeader").closest("div.containerClass")
```

Comment: Am I just confused or can't you just do `$('div.containerClass.containerHeader')`... doesn't the element have both classes?

Comment: @fudgey - `:has()` means it has a *descendant* with that class :)

Comment: Your first example had nearly identical performance to my 2nd example in my question. Your second example did not work for me.... is it functionally equivalent to my example?

Comment: @frankadelic - It should be, yes, though your ID is `section-wrapper` and I have this truncated (was just `section-wrapp` in my answer) when I pasted, it's fixed not.

Comment: Your second example didn't work for my HTML, even with the correct id selector.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be silly if this is indeed faster, have you tried:

```
$("div.containerClass > div.containerHeader").parents('div.containerClass')
```

on edit: Added parent selector.